# Google Cloudrun commit container changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to commit a container’s file changes or settings into a new image from the Google Cloudrun container(service)

Similar to `docker commit` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/  is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, the revision, and the running container are immutable. Only the /tmp directory can be written.

You need to create a new container and to deploy a new revision. It's better for versioning (and rollback), and above all for the security!